# I can't seem to subtract one variable from another

Tags: javascript, subtraction

I'm working on a simple game and I've gotten as far as coding it so that when you click on an attack button it should generate a random number based on a base and strength then subtract that from the enemy's health but the subtracting part doesn't seem to work. It always outputs `NaN`.

```
<head>
    <script>
    var playerHealth=100;
    var enemyHealth=100;
    var strength=10;

    function begin(){
        document.getElementById('playerhealth').innerHTML = playerHealth;
        document.getElementById('enemyhealth').innerHTML = enemyHealth;
        }

    function hitEnemy(){
        var attack=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + strength);
        var enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attack;
        document.getElementById('damage').innerHTML = attack;   
        document.getElementById('enemyhealth').innerHTML = enemyHealth;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="begin()">
        <input type="button" name="doit" id="doit" value="Attack!" onclick="hitEnemy();">
        <br /><span>playerhealth</span>
        <div style="font-size:3em;" id="playerhealth"></div>
        <span>enemyhealth</span>
        <div style="font-size:3em;" id="enemyhealth"></div>
        <br />
        <span>You Did:</span><span style="font-size:3em;" id="damage"></span><span>damage</span>

</body>
```

It may have something to do with not specifically making sure that they're integers but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you redefine the enemyHealth var inside hitEnemy function. Remove the var to fix it.

```
 function hitEnemy(){
        var attack=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + strength);
        enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attack;
        document.getElementById('damage').innerHTML = attack;   
        document.getElementById('enemyhealth').innerHTML = enemyHealth;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the most immediate problem.  You need to remove `var` from the `enemyHealth` decalaration inside of `hitEnemy`.  This creates a new variable named `enemyHealth` intsead of modifying the first one.

```
enemyHealth = enemyHealth - parseFloat(attack);
```

Additionally you should be calling `begin` at the end of every `hitEnemy` call in order to update the scores.  Here's a working version of the code

- http://jsfiddle.net/YbCay/

Comment: @user1026779 - Make sure you accept JaredPar's answer. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jared's response...

```
var enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attack;
```

is shorthand for...

```
var enemyHealth;
enemyHealth = enemyHealth - attack;
```

First, `enemyHealth` is defined as `undefined`* within the scope of `hitEnemy`. Now, *two* variables named `enemyHealth` exist, but the inner one "shadows" the outer one, making it impossible to refer to the outer one. So, `attack` is subtracted from `undefined`, producing `NaN`.

* which sounds nonsensical, I know